# How is rdf Encoded for fast retrieval?

Tags: rdf, encode, triplestore

I'm reading on rdf and web schema and came across [this statement](http://cs.ulb.ac.be/public/teaching/projh402). "To ensure that the knowledge is encoded for fast retrieval, the RDF store will first encode all variable-length URLs in the dataset by fixed-width integers, among other things. Each RDF triple will then be encoded by their corresponding integer triples (integer_of_subject, integer_of_property, integer_of_object)."
I don't understand what or where are these fixed width integers? how are these corresponding integers found or created? I'm at a loss I search for encoding but only get more confused.

Comment: It is about triplestores, not about semantic markup. On storage level, for efficiency reasons, miscellaneous hashes, GUIDs or just sequential numbers might be used for internal represention of URIs.
Look into those articles on HAT-tries referenced in the project proposal or into chapters 3–6 in _Groppe S. Data Management and Query Processing in Semantic Web Databases_.

Comment: for hat-tries each container has a fixed size which then splits if full taking the first letter of the string. Each container has a fixed size and fixed amount of slot to a pointer as every container has the hashed Int value of the string being searched. But that is for a single string. If implementing an rdf and starting with the Subject will the pointer point to a string(subject) and then point to another container to search for the predicate and then finally a pointer to the object?